The Quant Version of the Intel ISEF for High Schoolers
I am high-school senior who is interested in quantitative finance (and has been since 2021) and wishes to pursue it as a future career.  I've studied options pricing; I've traded derivatives; I used matplotlib to graph in 3D the Black-Scholes Equations and their related greeks; I used LaTex to write all my notes on the math behind the Black-Scholes Equations and assembled my 3D (V,S,T) graphs (also some PL graphs for the different strategies); ... For a college application one often writes some sort of a paper and makes some sort of a presentation at a science fair/ competition (like the Intel ISEF) and claims the credit on their college application.  But I have devoted much of my time and energy in developing a Financial Derivatives Visualization System (Using OpenGL to create 3D graphics (the goal is to match 3Blue1Brown)) and studying financial derivatives.  Although I do not claim that my skills are ever worth anything professionally, I do wish to present the results of my investigations and my development of the visualization software in some forum that can get me credit.  This is what I'm passionate about, and I do not wish to compete in some science fair or do medical research (like what many of my relatives did) purely for the sake of the college application.  Do any of you know of a reputable forum where I can make a presentation of my software (sort of like in a science fair)?

Maybe you could try to ask on r/quant, your question does not quite fit here.

Thank you.  I will try to post the question there as well.  But, I saw several career questions similar to this on this forum; that's why I posted the question here.  I've just been so used to asking on this forum.

Best case would to talk to recruiters or apply to conferences (but conferences usually require a research paper). Maybe you can write one?

Bloomberg has monthly seminar (here is the September, 2024 one: https://go.bloomberg.com/attend/invite/09-30-24-bloomberg-quant-bbq-seminar-series ) with the format - one long talk, many "lightning" (5-minute) talks, yours sounds like a possible fit for the latter.

What is the bar of entry for the Bloomberg one?  Professionals have a funny of not replying to my emails.  My work is mostly on writing the software.  I guess I can write a paper, but it wouldn’t be about a specific research topic (more like a bunch of observations from the graphs that the software drew and the structure of the software itself).  Do papers usually have to be peer-reviewed or published for conferences?
